# Connection between affine hyperspaces, such that one of them is contained in another one, and their equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let affine subspaces $H$, $K$ of a real vector space, of arbitrary dimension, given by:
$$
H=\{x\in X: f(x)=c\}, \textrm{ where } f\in X', f\neq 0, c\in \mathbb R,
$$

$$
K=\{x\in X: g(x)=d\}, \textrm{ where } g\in X', g\neq 0, d\in \mathbb R,
$$
be such that 
$$
H\subset K.
$$
Is there an $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $g=af$ and $d=ac$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in H$, then $H - x = \ker f$, so $\ker f \subseteq K - x = \ker g$.

Given now any $x_0 \in X$ with $f(x_0) = 1$, we have for every $x \in X$ that $x - f(x)x_0 \in \ker f\subseteq \ker g$, hence 
$$ 0 = g(x) - f(x)g(x_0) \iff g(x) = g(x_0)f(x)$$
so $g = g(x_0) \cdot f$, as $x$ was arbitrary.

Now let $x \in H$, then 
$$ d = g(x) = g(x_0) f(x) = g(x_0)c$$
That is $d = ac$, $g = af$ with $a = g(x_0)$.